# $each only for specific array in json

Tags: jquery, json

I am making a listview using JSON and are successfull with this, but... I was wandering if it was possible to send other data to my page, which is "not in an array" with the same JSON call without having to put them through the $each?

Here is my JSON: ---EDIT---

```
[{"menutime":"2013-04-23 19:23:42"},{"list":"menu1"},{"list":"Menu2"},{"list":"Menu3"}]
```

As you can see, I have 3 "list" which I get into an listview like this:

```
dataCallback = function (data) {
    var content = [];
    // var now = data.menutime; // HERE I WANT THE MENUTIME TO BE PUT INTO A VARIABLE //
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        content.push(val.list); // GETTING ALL THE MENUS //
    });
    $('#games').html(content.join('')).listview('refresh');
}
```

I don't get the menutime... How do I do this?

Thanks in advance :-)

---------------- EDIT ----------------

I have tried this like Kevin B has suggested but I cant get it to work?!

```
dataCallback = function(data){
    alert("Date: "+data.menutime);

    //var content = data.list.join("");
    //var now = data.menutime; // HERE I WANT THE MENUTIME TO BE PUT INTO A VARIABLE //

    $('#userbar').html(data.profile); // FETCHING USERS DATA FOR PROFILEBAR //
    //$('#games').html(content).listview('refresh');
}
```

In my alert I get "Undefined".

My "jason" looks like this:

```
([{"menutime":"2013-04-25 15:57:50"},{"profile":"troels"}])
```

Any ideas why this dont work?

Comment: `["list":"Menu2"}` believe me `[` should be `{`

Comment: you'd have to push `val.menutime`. You've also got a syntax error in your json: `...["list"...`, but that's probably just a transcription error.

Comment: The JSON posted as it is, is invalid. Is the top level structure an array?

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify what the server is returning, make it return data that is more appropriately structured for what it contains.

```
{ 
    "menutime": "2013-04-23 19:23:42",
    "list": ["menu1","menu2","menu3"]
}
```

Now your callback can be simpler:

```
dataCallback = function (data) {
    var content = data.list.join("");
    var now = data.menutime; // HERE I WANT THE MENUTIME TO BE PUT INTO A VARIABLE //
    $('#games').html(content).listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. You had my exact answer, except that the OP specified `''` as the `glue` for the join.

Comment: Ah, i missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinB - Can't get your example to work? Please read my initial edited post.

Comment: @Mansa My example only works if you change the JSON structure to what i posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing menutime -

```
content.push(val.menutime);
```

You json should look like this -

```
 [{"menutime":"2013-04-23 19:23:42"},{"list":"menu1"},{"list":"Menu2"},{"list":"Menu3"}]
```

Comment: Sorry..., My JSON looks like you describe, but still no luck?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your array inside a object

```
dataCallback = function (data) {
    var content = [];
    // var now = data.menutime; // HERE I WANT THE MENUTIME TO BE PUT INTO A VARIABLE //
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        content.push(val.list); // GETTING ALL THE MENUS //
    });
    var sendData = {
          content :content ,
          menutime:now
    };
    $('#games').html(sendData .content.join('')).listview('refresh');
    ///use sendData.menutime to get menutime
}
```

Comment: But, how does I get the "menutime" into an variable for it self?

Comment: Well, Now I dont get the list anymore?